# Package that deals with cgns format?

Tags: python, simulation, cgns

How to read cgns file contain mesh in python?

I found one package Pymesh but this package only deal with (read/write 2D and 3D mesh in .obj, .ply, .stl, .mesh).

Does anyone knows any package?

Comment: Does this help? http://www.hdfql.com/examples

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CGNS

Comment: thank you for link but my task is to read cgns file in python and on that file I want to perform computation. I found one package pyCGNS but I am not sure this package able to do what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the CGNS file is written with hdf5 (instead of the older ADF versions) you can open them with the python libraries `h5py` or `tables`. I use these to read my CGNS files and access them like any other hdf5 file. The same could be said for matlab or any other language... if you can read hdf5 you can read CGNS. I believe CGNS versions 3+ default to hdf5.

Answer (score 2):

PyCGNS libraries for CGNS end-users and Python application developpers. Here is link - http://pycgns.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

[meshio](https://github.com/nschloe/meshio) now has initial support for CGNS.